# Django filter and MySQL (SUBSTRING, LENGTH)

Tags: mysql, django, substring, django-filters

please tell me, how i can make query into database (mysql), with Django models filters. 
I want create select query like:

```
    SELECT word FROM core_dictionary WHERE LENGTH(word)=8 AND SUBSTRING(word,1,1)='А';
```

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to solve this problem only by using the "extra":

```
    d = Dictionary.objects.values_list('word').extra( where=['LENGTH(word)=%s'%(int(wordlen)*2), 'SUBSTRING(word,1,1)="%s"' % startchar] )
```

But i think is not good way....

Comment: `extra` is the best way to do this, but you should use the `params` argument rather than string interpolation to build your query.